# Why do I get negative dimensions are not allowed merging rasterio datasets?

Tags: pandas, numpy, rasterio

I am trying to use Python's rasterio library to analyze GIS wind data available [here](https://www.nrel.gov/gis/assets/images/us-wind-data.zip). I've written this reduced program:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio 
from rasterio.merge import merge

file1 = 'us-wind-data/wtk_conus_120m_mean_masked.tif'
file2 = 'us-wind-data/wtk_conus_140m_mean_masked.tif'

def f(old_data, new_data, old_nodata, new_nodata, index=None, roff=None, coff=None):
    old_data[:] = np.maximum(old_data, new_data)

with rio.open(file1, dtype=np.float64) as test1, rio.open(file2, dtype=np.float64) as test2:
    mosaic, out_trans = merge([test1, test2], method=f)
    print(mosaic)
```

and when running this I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge5.py", line 16, in <module>
    mosaic, out_trans = merge([test1, test2], method=f)
  File "/home/mmachenry/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasterio/merge.py", line 261, in merge
    dest = np.zeros((output_count, output_height, output_width), dtype=dt)
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

There are a lot of examples of this error on Stackoverflow. None that I've found seem to be what I'm doing. It is, after all, a low level numpy error. In my research I've found people experiencing issues with reading the data as default float16 and then getting math overflow errors producing negatives. So I bumped up my dtype to float64 and it did not improve the situation.

I'm attempting to write a simple function that will take several of these tif files with a wind speed at each data point and create a new tif file with my data point that is a function of all of the wind speeds.

Answer (score 0):

What's so mysterious about?

```
In [142]: np.zeros((10,-2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-142-c7db7030b12c>", line 1, in <module>
    np.zeros((10,-2))
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

One or more of

```
(output_count, output_height, output_width)
```

But not knowing anything about `merge` or `rasterio` I don't know where those dimensions come from.

Can you tell us anything about `test1, test2` when this error occurs.

As writen this question is not reproducible - it involves files that we don't have access to (and probably don't want either).

Comment: I did link to the files in the original question.